# Is it possible to externalize Electron menu template code?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an `Electron` app with 3 windows and each window has a different menu. The menu template code for each menu is quite long and I would like to externalize it. So far nothing I have tried works.

I've tried different ways to "modularize" it but got lots of errors. The approach below works to set up the menu, but none of the functions referenced in the menu work (e.g. `quitApplication`).

Is what I am trying to do not possible or am I just "doing it wrong"?

[image]

```
var test = require("./app/js/menuTest.js");
var tm = new test();    
var menuTemplate = tm.getMenu();
myWindow = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
```

---

**menuTest.js**

```
function testMenu() {
 this.getMenu = function () {
        var menuTemplate = [
            {
                label: global.productData.appName,
                submenu: [
                    { label: 'About ' + global.productData.appName, click: () => { showAboutWindow() } },

                    { type: 'separator' },
                    { role: 'hide' },
                    { role: 'hideothers' },
                    { role: 'unhide' },
                    { type: 'separator' },
                    { label: 'Quit', click: () => { quitApplication() }, accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+q' }
                ]
         // code deleted for clarity
        return menuTemplate;
    }
}
module.exports = testMenu;
```

Comment: where have you imported those `quitApplication()` and `showAboutWindow()` functions inside the code ?

Comment: Those functions are in my `main.js` where I am setting up the menus. My guess is that my `require` puts the menu template code in a separate context – so those functions are not found. Confusing.

Comment: yes of course those functions need to be in the same context you are calling from or you simply can put those functions in window object check if those functions are available in global context of window and then execute them.

Comment: @AneesIjaz - thanks. Yeah, that starts to get a lot more complicated than simply externailzing the menu templates – there are a lot of function calls in each menu.

Comment: Have you checked that you can use `quitApplication()` outside your `testMenu` function? If so then it's just a closure problem. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the `getMenu` function inside the `testMenu` function. Why not just create a single function like `exports.getMenu = function () {` and use it like `test.getMenu()`?

Comment: the better way would be add the functions to the window scope like `window.quitApplication = function(){window.close();}` and that you will be able to access from this menu file also like `click = window.quitApplication`

Comment: @NoGrabbing Have you considered "injecting" the functions into the menu module? Depending on how many functions there are, this might get lengthy, but you could put them into an object and just pass the object into the module?

Comment: @snwflk - thanks for the comment. I was trying to simplify and "modularize" my `main.js` code by externalizing the menus but it seems like all the ways to do that successfully add a lot more complexity (for such a simple thing like reducing the line count by @ 300). I'm too busy, I've got bugs to write! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From how I understand your question, you want to move the template code out of your main process script, but keep the functions in there.

This can be achieved by moving the menu structure object into a separate module. The module exports a function that takes an object with references to the functions you want to call in the menu.

I believe this does not add significant complexity and "externalizes" just the menu template code.

**menu1.js:**

```js
module.exports = function(actions) {
    return [
        {
            label: "Foo",
            submenu: [
                { label: "Bar", click: actions.bar },
                { label: "About", click: actions.about }
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

**main.js:**

```js
const {app,BrowserWindow,Menu} = require("electron");

const actions = {
    bar: function () {
        console.log("bar");
    },
    about: function () {
        console.log("about");
    }
};

const menu1_template = require("./menu1.js")(actions);
const menu1 = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menu1_template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu1);

let mainWindow;

app.on("ready", function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();
});
```

Comment: That's clever. I didn't realize one could call `require` with an arg.

Comment: To be precise, that's not exactly what's happening: the `require("./menu1.js")` call returns the exported function, which we then call on the same line, but only because we wanted to reduce LOC. Of course one could make that call separately.

Comment: Ah, ok. I get it now.