# Create menubar outside principal process in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a menu on the electron which has a function to change the page when pressed. This menu works perfectly well in the main electron process, However, so that the main process file is not too long with the menu, I changed the menu to a preload and made the menu using the remote. However, when using remote.getCurrentWindow () with the loadFile method, the following warning is sent.

> Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been
>   closed or released. Function provided here: undefined

The menu code in a simplified way and the following

```
const {remote} = require('electron');
const { Menu } = remote

const win = remote.getCurrentWindow();

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
  {label: 'menu',
    submenu: [
      {label: 'item1',
        click: ()=>{win.loadFile('item1.html')}
      },
      {label: 'item2',
        click: ()=>{win.loadFile('item2.html')}
      },
      {label: 'item3',
        click: ()=>{win.loadFile('item3.html')}
      },
      {label: 'item4',
        click: ()=>{win.loadFile('item4.html')}
      },
    ]
  },
]);

Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

I didn't find in the documentation a way to change the page on the bar in a menubar.

I would like to know some way to fix this or a better way to create a menubar outside of main.js

Comment: I don't know  but I would try calling `getCurrentWindow` in the context of the menu action – something like: `remote.getCurrentWindow().loadFile('item1.html')` – because maybe the `const win` is out of scope. Just a guess.

Comment: It was one of the first things I tried to do, but the problem remained the same.

Comment: Ah well . . . I was bothered by how long the menu code is (I have 3 menus) and I tried to externalize them (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921598/is-it-possible-to-externalize-electron-menu-template-code) but that was leading to even more complex "solutions" so I just gave up and moved on.