# How to separate MenuItem method declaration and implementation across different modules in electron.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a BrowserWindow MenuItem defined as such

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const {mainMenuTemplate, createAddNewEmployee} = remote.require('./main');
...

mainMenuTemplate = [
    {
        label: 'Human-Resource',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Add New Employee',
                click() {
                    createAddNewEmployee();
                },
            },
            {
                label: 'Basic Information'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

What I would like to do is have this template and a few others as well defined in a separate file, say template.js, strictly for the purposes of readability and not wanting to clutter my main.js module since that is where I am creating my windows. Then, in the main.js module, I wanted to have the implementation for the method in such a manner:

```
exports createAddNewEmployee = function createAddNewEmployee (){
   // method implementation here
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting the error 'Browser window of undefined'. Am I going 
 about this the wrong way? Or is my only solution to just have everything in one file(main.js)? Please help.

Comment: fwiw – I tried this a few times and never found a solution that wasn't more confusing/cluttered than the massive menu template code. (e.g. Having menu code that calls a function in "main" results in error, etc.). Here's my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921598/is-it-possible-to-externalize-electron-menu-template-code

Comment: @spring, apologies for the late reply. I had a look at your link. It was very helpful indeed. You can post it here and I will accept it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @snwflk, definitely. Just accepted it. Many thanks to the both of you.